# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am trying to display the selected items values because I want to store them later into ArrayList to send them to the server. Currently when I select the items and click on the button the app crashes and I am gettting the fowllowing error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference`

How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

onCreate method in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.route_available);

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(4);
    arr.add(6);
    createCheckboxList(arr);

}
```

The createCheckboxList method in the MainActivity:

```
 private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {


        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
           CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
            cb.setId(i);
            ll.addView(cb);

        }
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i : items) {
                    //boolean checked = ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
                    CheckBox ch=(CheckBox) findViewById(i); 
                    if (ch.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                   "Button is clicked" + ch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bustracker.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Select route: "
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lila"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first for loop to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
       CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
        cb.setId(items.get(i));
        ll.addView(cb);

    }
```

Edit: To display all values in a single Toast, you can do something like

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = "";
            for (int i : items) {
                //boolean checked = ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
                CheckBox ch=(CheckBox) findViewById(i); 
                if (ch.isChecked()) {
                    message = message + " " + ch.getText() + " " ;                   
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Button is clicked " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Comment: I changed `CheckBox ch=(CheckBox) findViewById(i);` to `CheckBox ch=(CheckBox) MainActivity.this.findViewById(i);` but I am still getting the same error?!

Comment: Could you post your onCreate() method where you are calling createCheckBoxList() method along with the parameters?

Comment: I have posted it please see my updated question code.

Comment: You're adding 2, 4, 6 to your ArrayList. What are those? You need to pass the id of the checkboxes in your layout file. They should look like R.id.checkbox1, R.id.checkbox2 etc. Anyway, could you also show me your layout file where you have defined all your checkboxes?

Comment: I want to create that programmatically also I have in my xml file just linearlayout to add all the stuff into it I dont have any checkboxes there since I dont know the number and values of the checkboxes?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to pass ArrayList<Integer> to the method and I want to craete a checkbox list for these values.

Comment: Try changing it to `CheckBox ch=(CheckBox) ll.findViewById(i);`. See if it works.

Comment: If I change the loop like this it crashes and I am not getting the arrayList value displayed I am getting the `i` value of the for loop displayed

Comment: I changed the loop back to your old loop with minor changes. See if it works.

Comment: it is better I am not getting the error but the Toast it is like `Button is clicked android.widget.CheckBox{2a7445 VFED..C....0,0964, 192 #2}`

Comment: I want to get all the values of the checkboxes and not just once when I clicked the button.

Comment: That's normal. You are getting the Checkbox object and you are displaying it in your Toast. What did you want to display in your Toast?

Comment: You will get the values one by one in a Toast message since you are displaying it inside a loop..

Comment: Ok i fixed that with `ch.getText()` is not it possible to display all the values when the button is clicked and not just once after the other?

Comment: You can store all the ch.getText() values in a variable and then display it in a Toast once the loop is over. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the id of the check box to items.get(i) not i

Comment: do you mean this line `CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) ll.findViewById(i);` to  `CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) items.get(i);` I am getting `Cannot cast from Integer to CheckBox`

Comment: No, i mean this line cb.setId(i); to cb.setId(items.get(i));